# broken cement board corner

Tags: shower, tile, cement-board, thinset

[image: picture of broken cement board corner]
i installed a cement board with a badly crushed corner.
how should i proceed?

- This is for a shower it will be waterproofed with redguard (or
  equivalent).
- There is studs behind the screws on the right and left.

I don't know if its worth the effort (or if its even necessary) to
   patch this corner with new cement board.

Comment: i am planning on 1) just patching it with plain thinset other options are two 2) mix mud mortar into the thinset 3) try to cut out just this corner and fasten a patch of new board to the two studs shown in the picture 4)remove the whole board and start again

Answer (score 1):

Add mortar with either fiberglass or a kerdi membrane let set then add another layer of membrane to the corners as required for usual install.